# Multiple row insert in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

Hi I need to update multiple rows in a table so I wrote below query, but it only updates the first row and not the others. Please help.

Query:

```
String sql = "REPLACE INTO subscriber_metadata (msisdn, have_had_speech_pkg, have_had_sms_pkg, created, changed) values ";
```

Comment: to less information. you post only a single sql statement. where is the rest of your java code?

Comment: well I guess its only query which needs to be changed according to the primary key in table that's why I have submitted only my query.

Answer (score 2):

Well `REPLACE INTO` does the following `DELETE + INSERT`, what you're looking for is `UPDATE`, doc over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: NAIT actually what I want to replace few rows from the table according to the key. I am trying to do it with a stringbuilder so can you just help me with the query only?

Comment: @S.Dey can you provide the complete query you're trying with `REPLACE INTO` ?

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE INTO is nothing more than a mechanical DELETE and INSERT. It can incite mysqld to address deadlocks (See my answer to [How I prevent deadlock occurrence in my application?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36481/how-i-prevent-deadlock-occurrence-in-my-application/36515#36515))